# Get rid of Help Text in reset password form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Django offers an simple and fast option for "Forget password" by overriding the default templates.

Some of these forms come with help text

The password_reset_confirm which I get the reset link from the email, I don't know how to get rid of the help text messages.

It is displayed in the
password_reset_confirm.html, by using {{ form.as_p}}

Is there any way to remove the help text, without extending the ResetPasswordForm in forms.py to set the help text to none.

It's complicated as the url for this form takes token.

I tried this, but I'm almost sure it wouldn't work.

**forms.py**

```
class ResetPassword(PasswordResetForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("new_password1", "new_password2")
        model = get_user_model()
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["new_password1"].help_text = None
```

**views.py**

```
class resetpassword(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):

    template_name = "registration/password_change_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_complete')
    form_class = forms.ResetPassword

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(resetpassword, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = kwargs.pop('instance')

        return kwargs
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to override the help_texts in the `Meta`:

```
class ResetPassword(PasswordResetForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("new_password1", "new_password2")
        model = get_user_model()
        help_texts = {
            'new_password1': '',
            'new_password2': '',
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that there's no way to access the view, the url to this form is like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/reset/Mjg/4jo-ebb58be64e6eaf6abd96/, Idk how to set up a url to acess this view, once it takes a token.